# How do you incorporate WKInterfaceSKScene into a watchOS Starter Template App?

Tags: game-development, watchos, apple-developer

I'm trying to create a Apple Watch game using Xcode 14.2 and watchOS 9.  Getting started creating a watchOS App [seems pretty straight forward](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-a-watchos-app), and getting started creating a game project via the starter template [seems easy enough](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-an-xcode-project-for-an-app).  Trying to put these two together though doesn't seem to work (or is not straight foward).  The documentation specifies limitations on what libraries can be used with watchOS noting [WKInterfaceSKScene](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfaceskscene), but doesn't give any specific examples of how to start out a WatchOS project using this.  Additionally nearly every online tutorial that I'm able to find uses Storyboards to create a watchOS game, which does not seem to be supported in the latest version of watchOS or Xcode.  Can anyone provide example starter code using the watchOS App project starter that that loads with a small colored square on the screen that moves from left to right using the WKInterfaceSKScene library?

I've tried the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-a-watchos-app), asking ChatGPT for a sample or reference links, and the below tutorials:
[Make an Apple Watch Game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qp6fhJ8LL1w)
[How to Setup a Sprite Kit based Watch OS 3 App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEp3bj9PhYg)
[Animations on Apple Watch with SpriteKit](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/animations-on-apple-watch-with-spritekit-665b981e7b64)
[Build a Simon game for watchOS](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/143/build-a-simon-game-for-watchos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it looks like the official Apple documentation here is a bit misleading.  WKInterfaceSKScene is not needed, you can simply use SprikeKit for this. I was able to get a cyan ball to fall and bounce mid screen on the watch by modifying the [Pong example](https://github.com/kodecocodes/wos-materials/tree/editions/1.0/03-digital-crown/projects/starter/Pong) from the [watchOS with SwiftUI book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1950325555).  You can setup the same starter project for yourself by following the below steps:

1. Start a watchOS App in XCode.
2. Create a new swift file (which will be your game scene and put the code shown below in it).
3. Modify the ContentView file by importing SpriteKit and SwiftUI and by modifying the body variable in the ContentView struct to look like the below.
4. Build your project and it should show a cyan ball that falls and bounces mid screen.

ContentView.swift

```swift
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            SpriteView(scene: GameScene(size: reader.size))
                .focusable()
        }
    }
```

GameScene.swift

```swift
final class GameScene: SKScene {
    private let cyan = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    private var ball: SKShapeNode!
    
    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // This was created via autofix
        fatalError("This should never be called")
    }
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        super.update(currentTime)
    }
}

extension GameScene {
    override func sceneDidLoad() {
        super.sceneDidLoad()
        ball = createBall()
        addChild(ball)
        let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
        border.friction = 0
        border.restitution = 1
        physicsBody = border
    }
    
    func createBall() -> SKShapeNode {
        let node = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 15)
        node.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
        node.fillColor = cyan
        let body = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 15)
        body.linearDamping = 0
        body.angularDamping = 0
        body.restitution = 1.0
        node.physicsBody = body
        return node
    }
}
```